# MySQL workbench -> Export Forward Engineering Script

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Somehow I've changed a setting or something so that now when I export the database as a forward engineering script it adds an empty `COMMENT ''` string after ever column in every table.  Has anyone experienced this and how can I make it stop?

I'ved carefully checked all settings/preferences I can find.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled.  I've deleted the entire MySQL folder under `User/AppData/Roaming`  I don't know what else to try.  My fellow developers (I've had 2 try) do not experience the rogue comments at the end.  Yes I am using the latest database.mwb file freshly checked out from SVN then same as everyone else.

Even though it's harmless, it still causes problems because then as Gold Copy changes are made the to database schema it'll look like I was the last one to edit every column of every table which will not work.
Here is a sample of some of the columns:

```
`required` TINYINT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `created_timestamp` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `created_by_userid` CHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `modified_timestamp` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
```

How can I get rid of the `COMMENT ''`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  Apparently it's caused by the latest version of the MySQL workbench.  `6.3`.  I had tried a much earlier version of the workbench and while it hadn't spit out the COMMENT it had spit out other weird things, but I didn't try nearer to latest version until just barely and apparently that solves it.  So MySQL workbench `6.2.5` correctly spits out no comments when there aren't any to be had.

Comment: Are you saying 6.3.4 does have this problem and 6.2.5 does not? And that your fellow developers do not experience problems with either version? Same operating systems and MySQL server versions?

Comment: @PhilipOlson Turns out my fellow developers had the earlier version.  I know I know...should have been one of the first things I checked.  I haven't asked any developers to try the earlier version.  I'll do that tomorrow and verify that they have the same COMMENT troubles.  They're all gone for the day.

Comment: It looks like there is an open bug against 6.3.4 for this, please confirm if it looks like the one you suffer from. It appears the MySQL server version is important here (5.5 vs 5.6?):  http://bugs.mysql.com/77910

Comment: @PhilipOlson I'm not sure it's the exact same bug.  We don't get an Enum error, the fwd engineering script is executable it just has a bunch of extemporaneous COMMENTs in it.  Our version of MySQL is old we're running 5.1.  However that bug report does show the same empty string COMMENTs being generated.